# How to nest multiple results in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j, and I have a graph like this:

A `Collection` has many `Image`s:

```
(`Collection`)-[:contains]->(`Image`)
```

An `Image` has many `Tag`s:

```
(`Image`)-[:has_tag]->(`Tag`)
```

I want to select my `Collection`s with some condition, collecting linked images and tags in a nested structure, so that every row contains a distinct `Collection`, the related images and a list of tags for every image.

```
MATCH (c:`Collection`) WHERE some_condition_on(c) OPTIONAL MATCH (i:`Image`)<-[:contains]-(c) OPTIONAL MATCH (i)-[:has_tag]->(t:`Tag`) RETURN i, collect(????)
```

For example, here's how the output may be:

```
Node:`Collection `, [
    [Node:`Image`, [Node:`Tag`, Node:`Tag`, Node:`Tag`, Node:`Tag`]],
    [Node:`Image `, [Node:`Tag`, Node:`Tag`, Node:`Tag`, Node:`Tag`]],
    [Node:`Image `, [Node:`Tag`, Node:`Tag`, Node:`Tag`, Node:`Tag`]]
]
```

Is there a way to obtain this using neo4j collection functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
MATCH (c:Collection)-[:contains]->(i:Image)-[:has_tag]->(t:Tag)
WITH c, [i, COLLECT(t)] AS imgs
RETURN c, COLLECT(imgs) AS images;
```

Each row will have a `Collection` node, and an array that is structured like this example:

```
[
  [(:Image),
    [(:Tag)]
  ],
  [(:Image),
    [(:Tag), (:Tag)]
  ],
  [(:Image),
    [(:Tag)]
  ]
]
```

NOTE: The above simple example will only return collections that have at least one image, and images that have at least one tag.